# Flutter and the Design System

Tags: android, flutter

i've already worked on a `Design System` using native `Android(Java)`, and now i'm going to start working on a new `Design System` with using `Flutter`, but m'm not very familiar with `Flutter`, i have some questions that i didn't get answered by looking on the internet.

**On Android I have `colors.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    //Brand Primary colors
    <color name="color_primary" category="color">#FDE6E3</color>
    <color name="color_secondary" category="color">#FE918D</color>

</resources>
```

how would I make this `color` file in `Flutter`?

**On Android I have `dimen.xml`:**

```
    <resources>    
  //Font Sizes
  <dimen name="font_XXS" category="font-size">12sp</dimen>
  <dimen name="font_size_XS" category="font-size">16sp</dimen>


  
  //Spacing Inline
  <dimen name="spacing_XS" category="spacing-inline">4dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="spacing_XXS" category="spacing-inline">8dp</dimen>
  
  
  //Border Radius
  <dimen name="border_radius_none" category="radius">0dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="border_radius_XS" category="radius">4dp</dimen>
  

  //Border Width
  <dimen name="border_width_none" category="border-width">0dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="border_width_medium" category="border-width">2dp</dimen>

  
</resources>
```

how would I make this `dimen` file in `Flutter`?

On Android, i put it all together to create a `Link` component.

```
public class CustomLink extends AppCompatTextView {

private Context mContext;

public CustomLink(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
}

public CustomLink(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.mContext = context;

    TypedArray attrsArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomLink,
            0, 0);
    initializeCustomLink();
    attrsArray.recycle();
}


private void initializeCustomLink() {
    initializeLinkContainer();

}

private void initializeLinkContainer() {
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    this.setLinkTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary)); //Here I use a Design feature

    this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_secondary)); //Here I use a Design System feature

    this.setTextSize((getResources.getDimension.font_XXS) / (int) scale); //Here I use a Design System feature

    this.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


   }

}
```

**How would I do these basic things in `Flutter`?**

Answer (score 0):

Under common folder, you should keep your constant data

[image]

Here the link: https://github.com/dicodingacademy/a199-flutter-expert-project/tree/main/lib